# Can I fix a D5200 with 200mm lens that doesn't autofocus correctly after being dropped?

Tags: autofocus, troubleshooting, equipment-damage

When first bought, my Nikon D5200 worked like a champ! Now everything has a fuzziness to it and the auto focus doesn't quite focus and you can't see the details of a picture taken. It's ruining my love for photography!

I've tried using all the cleaning capabilites on my camera. It doesn't matter what lens I use, still the same result. My camera was knocked off a table and the 200mm lens that was on the camera broke inside. Something isn't right. Should I take it in to a camera shop?

Comment: Have you tried using Live View to auto focus? Manually focusing using Live View? Can you manually focus the lens to get a better picture than with AF?

Answer (score 2):

Getting a D5200 repaired is probably going to cost more than a replacement.
If you dropped it & broke something, talk to your insurance company.

Just in the vain hope it is something in software, try a full reset.
With the camera switched on, hold the MENU & INFO buttons for 2 seconds or so, until the screen switches off briefly. [On any Nikon camera, it's the two buttons with green dots, though their location is not always the same on different models]

[image]

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/471723/Nikon-D5200.html?page=70

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you first need to determine if it's the lens, or if the camera is damaged. This is easy to diagnose: put a different lens on the camera, and see if it autofocuses with the different lens. Then, put your 200mm lens on a different Nikon body, and see if the other camera with your lens produces in-focus images.

If you don't have another Nikon camera body or another F-mount lens available, some suggestions are:

- Bring them into a local camera shop and ask if you can use a different camera and lens with your equipment for some quick testing (if that's possible; most local camera shops have been shutting down for the last several years)
- Ask if a friend or coworker has compatible camera gear to test with.
- Try to find a local photography club or group to meet up with. People love to bring gear and let others try them out.
- Rent an inexpensive Nikon body and F-mount lens to try. There are several internet-based photography gear rentals out there. LensRentals.com, for one, if you are U.S.-based.

If the D5200 is damaged, as Tessujin's answer states, it would probably cost more to repair than it would to find a used one. You didn't state which 200mm lens you have, but the same case may apply. (Although, if your lens is the Nikkor 200mm f/2 VR II, I'd definitely try to get it repaired.)

Comment: Perhaps adding to your list of things to try:  attempt to manually focus or use CDAF in LV to see if the main issue is AF or lens/mount/sensor alignment?

Comment: You should also check that the lens mount is still straight and hasn't been yanked out of alignment by the inertia of a 200mm lens. This could be confirmed by shooting perpendicularly a page of newspaper (or anything flat with enough detail, possibly a brick wall or a wall with a textured cover) and see if there is a straight line across the shot where everything is still in focus (more or less accidental  [tilt/shift effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt%E2%80%93shift_photography)).